# Do you want to start? Random Module Game

Tags: python, random

So I'm a **new programmer**, in the basis of python, I want to create a little game with the random module;However,I have problem with start button. I want to decide player to whether start or not. What should I do to defeat this problem or what code should you prefer. Leave your choices in below plzz<3.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more precise in your question. If you mean just decide randomly if the user should start or no and use a function from the random module to achieve that, go simple with the `choice` function.

`from random import choice`
`choices = choice(["Start", "Don’t start"])`

Comment: Ok I will take that in consideration. But now it says invalid syntax

Comment: Try now, quotes was the problem because i answered from mobile.